# Internet Explorer Tells me The Cache for forward and backward ist deakivated

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, internet-explorer-9, tinymce-4

I've got an problem with an ruby on rails aplication.

I've got a Textarea with the TinyMCE editor.

so if I call the page every thing is okay. But If I want to save or leave the page I got the Message If I really want to leave the page?

[image]

How can I avoid this problem?

I've got a https page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats probably a Problem while saving? are you using something like the tinyMCE oder CKeditor?

Check the configuration of those.

Comment: Yeah thanks, sorry have forgotton to send my solution. The Problem was a miss configuration of the TinyMCE editor.

Comment: Sounds more like a comment than answer!

Comment: hadn't had the reputation to write a comment ;)